# JPQL for a Unidirectional OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, jpql

I need a jpql query for my Spring repository interface method, to retrieve all Posts for a given Semester.

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@JoinTable
(
 name = "semester_post",
 joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "semester_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
 inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "post_id", referencedColumnName = "id", unique = true)}
)
private List<PostEntity<?>> posts = new ArrayList<>();
```

PostEntity doesn't have a reference to Semester, and I do not want to add one, because I plan to use this PostEntity for other things than Semester. Maybe I'll have another class (let's say Group) which will also have a OneToMany of PostEntity (like the one in Semester)

**So, how do I write this SQL query as a JPQL one ?**

```
select * from posts join semester_post on semester_post.post_id = posts.id where semester_post.semester_id = 1;
```

My repository

```
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<PostEntity, Long> {

String QUERY = "SELECT p FROM PostEntity p ... where semester = :semesterId";

@Query(MY_QUERY)
public List<PostEntity> findBySemesterOrderByModifiedDateDesc(@Param("semesterId") Long semesterId);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A query which will get you the result that you need is:

```
SELECT p FROM SemesterEntity s JOIN s.posts p WHERE s.id = :semesterId
```

This query uses the JOIN operator to join the `SemesterEntity` to the `PostEntity` across the `posts` relationship. By joining the two entities together, this query returns all of the `PostEntity` instances associated with the relevant `SemesterEntity`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @sina72, of course it answers the question. OP asks what is the JPQL for that SQL, and this is exactly what should be used.

Comment: Posting code alone is not very helpful. I am missing an explanation if and why this helps. Anyway, please excuse my auto-text comment, it is missing guidance, too.

Comment: I probably deserve it... Although 'SELECT p FROM SemesterEntity' simply didn't make sense for me at the time. I would expect it to return semesters not posts. I'll try to document more. I really post on SO only after I waste days on things I know may have a simple solution. Thank you.

Comment: There, is that better? :-)